# Deleting a column in a range stops a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete all the columns on a sheet that contain certain text in their top rows. Same code with just the Cell.EntireColumn colouring of the cell that matches the text works perfectly fine.

Doing it backwards didn't help. Setting a new range and then deleting the entire column does work but I have to run the code several times until it deletes all the columns.

```
For Each Cell in newRange
    Cell.EntireColumn.Delete
```

Otherwise when I would do it with a Do Loop I would get an error at the end.

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Source As Range
Set Source = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count))
Dim strWords As Variant
strWords = Array("Number", "First Name")

For Each Cell In Source
    For i = UBound(strWords) To LBound(strWords) Step -1
        If InStr(UCase(Cell), UCase(strWords(i))) > 0 Then 
        Cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    Next i
Next

End Sub
```

On this line in the very first loop I get the error:
     "Run-time error '424':
      Object Required"

```
If InStr(UCase(Cell), UCase(strWords(i))) > 0 Then
```

Update: Adding the values to a range works perfectly and the speed increase is noticeable with larger files. Thank you all for contributing!

An additional thing I need to do would be

```
If InStr(UCase(Cell), UCase(strWords(i))) 'is not in string Then
'Add to a union that will later be deleted
```

I tried this one but it would delete all the columns instead of just those not containing one of the strings.

```
If InStr(UCase(Cell), UCase(strWords(i))) = 0
```

Comment: You should setup a union first and then delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exit the `For i` loop after you delete `Cell` otherwise the `i` loop still trys to access the cell that was deleted.

```
For Each Cell In Source
    For i = UBound(strWords) To LBound(strWords) Step -1
        If InStr(UCase(Cell), UCase(strWords(i))) > 0 Then 
            Cell.EntireColumn.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next Cell
```

Or even better collect all cells (using `Union()`) and delete them in the end (much faster)

```
Dim ColsToDelete As Range

For Each Cell In Source
    For i = UBound(strWords) To LBound(strWords) Step -1
        If InStr(UCase(Cell), UCase(strWords(i))) > 0 Then 
            If ColsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set ColsToDelete = Cell.EntireColumn
            Else
                Set ColsToDelete = Union(ColsToDelete, Cell.EntireColumn)
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next Cell

'delete all collected colmuns in the end at once
If Not ColsToDelete Is Nothing Then ColsToDelete.Delete
```

Note that when you use `union()` you don't need necessarily loop backwards `Step -1` a forward loop will work too because you delete all of the rows at once in the end and while you loop your row numbers don't change anymore.

To also collect the columns you don't delete (see comments below and edited question).

```
Dim ColsToDelete As Range
Dim ColsToKeep As Range, IsDeleted As Boolean

For Each Cell In Source
    IsDeleted = False 'initialize
    For i = UBound(strWords) To LBound(strWords) Step -1
        If InStr(UCase(Cell), UCase(strWords(i))) > 0 Then 
            IsDeleted = True
            If ColsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set ColsToDelete = Cell.EntireColumn
            Else
                Set ColsToDelete = Union(ColsToDelete, Cell.EntireColumn)
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If Not IsDeleted Then
        If ColsToKeep Is Nothing Then
            Set ColsToKeep = Cell.EntireColumn
        Else
            Set ColsToKeep = Union(ColsToKeep, Cell.EntireColumn)
        End If   
    End If 
Next Cell

'delete all collected rows in the end at once
If Not ColsToDelete Is Nothing Then ColsToDelete.Delete
```

*Note that I changed the variable name `RowsToDelete` to `ColsToDelete` because it was named wrong.*

Comment: This works great, thank you for your help!  Just for curiosity how do I do this if a keyword is not found? Adding a  = 0  deletes everything.

Comment: @Setty you can add `If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then` to test if rows to delete were found or not.

Comment: @PEH Sorry I meant when I want a range of the columns where there is no keyword. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Setty I don't understand. Please be much more precise and give an example. You can also edit your original question to explain it (probably a comment is not enough).

Comment: @PEH Yea sorry for the lack of clarity. I added an example in my post.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a more effecient process by deleting everything at the end. Try this...

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Source As Range
Set Source = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count))
Dim strWords As Variant
strWords = Array("Number", "First Name")

Dim killRNG As Range
Set killRNG = Cells(1, Columns.Count).EntireColumn

For Each Cell In Source
    For i = UBound(strWords) To LBound(strWords) Step -1
        If InStr(UCase(Cell), UCase(strWords(i))) > 0 Then
        Set killRNG = union(killRNG, Cell.EntireColumn)
        End If
    Next i
Next


killRNG.Delete (xlLeft)
```

Comment: More efficient to `Exit For` after the `Union` so if it was marked for deletion because of `"Number"` it doesn't need to check for `"First Name"` too. Not much gain with only 2 words in the array but there might be more.

Comment: This `killRNG = uniont(killRNG, Cell.EntireColumn)`  should be `Set killRNG = union(killRNG, Cell.EntireColumn)`

Comment: Good grief, don't you ever sleep @Pᴇʜ? I'm at a bar was doing a great job impressing the Computer Science girls until you just big-leagued me. Thanks a lot. You're probaby right, I just typed up something fast to try to get a solution.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks! I fixed the set. I'll give you a tick so I can get one point closer to earning the "I'm a good f*ing sportsmanship! badge..."